# why not all html elements on vuejs component have data-v-??????? attribute?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

i use framework7-vue + vuejs. Components, like chip, have simple syntax:

```
<f7-chip text="Example Chip"></f7-chip>
```

and generate simple html:

```
<div data-v-aa85b83a="" class="chip">
    <div class="chip-label">Example Chip</div>
</div>
```

element `.chip` has `data-v` attribute, why `.chip-label` doesnt?
I need set style over `chip-label`, i know about /deep/ styling, but its shame. can i set data-v attribute to childrent elements dynamical components?

Comment: Please explain why you assume chip-label should have data-v attributes? Also why do you need that attribute in particular? Are you trying to do querySelector or similar against those elements?

Comment: sorry ) i need use scoped style for children elements, but they have not data-v attribute.

Comment: i know about deep selectors, but its shame ;)

Comment: It’s fine. Please add the scoped CSS you are tying to add to those elements and the issues you are experiencing please as well as what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have scss: 
```.chip{
            margin:0 5px 10px 0;
            /deep/ .chip-label{
                margin-top:-2px;
            }
        }```
i need scss:
```.chip{
            margin:0 5px 10px 0;
            .chip-label{
                margin-top:-2px;
            }
        }```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are either using `<style>` tags in your component (scoped styles) or you are viewing elements while running hot reload. This is more likely because of `scoped styles`, though.

Comment: yes, i need scoped style, i know about /deep/ styles, but why dynamical components not set data-v attribute to children elements?

Comment: Because they don't need them. Those `data-v-*` attributes are only used to set styling. Thats how scoped styles work - without them the scoped styling's wouldn't work.

Comment: Nope. Not unless you want to give them style.

Comment: ah, i was wondering why my nested html tags did not contain data-v-xxx attribute. Thank you @MattOestreich